# Reverse for Model with Slug in URL not working

Tags: django, reverse, generic-foreign-key

I have a parts.html page that references the model Part, the page I am having issue with is the Part List Generic Model view. The purpose of it is to list all of the parts on a page and show the category next to it. Each part has a foreignkey "category". I am trying to create a Slug URL from the Part list view to the Category detail page, but I receive this error when I go to the partlistview page. I can access the Category page with portal/category/category where the second category at the end is a category in the database.

Note: The entire python files below are to scale, I only pasted in relevant information, as it would be too much info.

```
django.urls.exceptions.NoReverseMatch: Reverse for 'category-detail' with arguments '('',)' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['portal/category/(?P<slug>[-\\w]+)/$']
```

**Views.py**

```
class PartDetailView(LoginRequiredMixin, generic.DetailView):
    model = Part
    template_name = 'portal/part.html'  # Option - Specify your own template name/location

class PartListView(LoginRequiredMixin, generic.ListView):
    model = Part
    #queryset = Part.objects.filter(is_active=True) #.prefetch_related('user') #hos

    paginate_by = 100
    https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2017/03/13/how-to-create-infinite-scroll-with-django.html
    template_name = 'portal/parts.html'  # Option - Specify your own template name/location
    context_object_name = 'part_list'

    #def get_queryset(self):
        #return Category.objects.all()

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
         context = super(PartListView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
         context['category'] = Category.objects.all()
         return context

class CategoryDetailView(LoginRequiredMixin, generic.DetailView):
    model = Category
    template_name = 'portal/category.html'  # Option - Specify your own template name/location
    slug_field = 'category'
    slug_url_kwarg = 'category'
```

**Models.py**

```
@python_2_unicode_compatible
class Category(BaseModel):
    """
    Model representing a part type (wiper, wheel, brake).
    """
    id = models.BigAutoField(primary_key=True)
    category = models.CharField(max_length=120, help_text=_("Category to organize parts into (wheel, wiperblade, brake)"))
    slug = models.SlugField(editable=False, unique=True, db_index=True)

    def __str__(self):  
        return '%s' % (self.category)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('portal:category-detail', kwargs={'slug': self.slug})  # str(self.trailer_number) kwargs={'slug': self.slug} instead of args=[self.slug]??

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.slug = slugify(self.category)
        super(Category, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'category'
        verbose_name = _('category')
        verbose_name_plural = _('categories')
        ordering = ['category']

@python_2_unicode_compatible
class Part(BaseModel):

    id = models.BigAutoField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=120, help_text=_("The unique name or part number to identify this particular item"))
    category =  models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.PROTECT, help_text='Category to organize parts into (wheel, wiperblade, brake)', related_name='part', null=True, blank=True) 
    brand = models.CharField(max_length=80, blank=True, help_text=_("The name of the manufacturer that originaly built this part"), null=True)  
    minimum_inventory_quantity = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(default=0, help_text=_("The minimum inventory quantity of this part before more need to be ordered"))

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('portal:part-detail', args=[str(self.id)])


    def __str__(self):  
        return '%s - %s' % (self.name, self.brand)


    class Meta:
        unique_together = ("name", "brand",)  #NOTE: Each SKU + Carrier should also be unique together  #unique_together = (("name", "manufacturer"), ("sku", "Carrier"))
        ordering = ["name", "brand",]
```

**Urls.py**

```
from django.conf.urls import url

from .views import PartDetailView, CategoryDetailView, PartListView, PartInstanceDetailView, PartVariantDetailView

urlpatterns = [

url(r'^parts/$', PartListView.as_view(), name='parts'),
    url(r'^parts/(?P<pk>\d+)/$', PartDetailView.as_view(), name='part-detail'),
url(r'^category/(?P<slug>[-\w]+)/$', CategoryDetailView.as_view(), name='category-detail'),

]
```

**parts.html**

```
<div class="table-responsive">
    <table class="table table-hover table-bordered table-striped">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Category</th> 



          <th>Name</th> 
          <th>Brand</th>
          <th>Model Number</th>
          <th>Variants</th>
          <th>Stock</th>
          <th>Locations</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        {% for part in part_list %}
          <tr>
            <td><strong><a href="{% url 'portal:category-detail' category.slug %}">{{ part.category.category }}</a></strong></td>
            <td><a href="{% url 'portal:part-detail' part.pk %}">{{ part.name }}</td>
            <td>{{ part.brand }}</td>
            <td>{{ part.part_variant.model_number }}</td>
            <td>{{ part.count_all }}</td>
            <td>{{ part.count_all }}</td>
            <td>{{ part.section.zone }}</td>
          </tr>
        {% empty %}
          {% if request.GET.q %}
            <tr>
              <td colspan="7" class="text-center bg-warning">No trailers found.</td>
            </tr>
          {% else %}
            <tr>
              <td colspan="7" class="text-center bg-warning">There are no trailers in the system.</td>
            </tr>
          {% endif %}
        {% endfor %}
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure but I think your *urls.py* need an `app_name = portal` before the urls list.

Read up more in the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/http/urls/#reversing-namespaced-urls).

Comment: Hmm, I only pasted the urls pertaining to the issue. I have about 30 other URLs that aren't shown that are working. I'll read the doc though

Comment: I'm not sure what the etiquette is about answering twice but I think it's allowed.

Comment: That didn't work, but ill make sure category.slug is actually returning something

Comment: Okay, so I made the changes that you mentioned. I typed the URL for the category into my url and it will go to the detailview that correlates with that slug "http://localhost:8000/portal/category/plc/". Still can't access my Parts page, because of the error in the way the slug is being called into the link

Comment: @Zalkota check the comment on the other answer.

Comment: Okay, now I have another issue. The URL only works when I uncomment the def get_queryset function for the Category. The Context function doesn't seem to be doing anything. Without the get_queryset no category data from the model registers. If I include the Def Get_queryset then the part model doesn't load..

Answer (score 0):

Your url pattern is expecting a keyword argument, but the `url` template tag is passing the *category slug* as an unnamed argument.

Just do this `{% url "portal:category-detail"  slug=category.slug %}`, 
because in your url pattern you named your capture group "slug".

Also, make sure `category.slug` is actually returning something.

Comment: @Zalkota I'm not sure I understand you completely. Did you add the `slug=category.slug` part to the url template tag? What's the error now? Is it still the same NoReverseMatch exception?